# Adding data from a Google Sheet to Firestore using Zapier

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I'm working on a project where I would need to keep product data from a google sheet up to date in a Firestore Collection. I have already found the possibility to use Zapier for this. Whenever I'm using a randomised Id, it works. But since this is about products, information changes so there is need for a fixed productId.

Screenshot from the working version in firebase:

[image: Firebase]

Unfortunately, when I add an Id, and then link the Firebase id, I get an error that the record is already added. But as you can see in the Zapier settings screenshot, it is stated that it will update known Id. So, I guess the firebase step in Zapier wants to create new collections while it should set data.

[image: Zapier settings]

> error:
>   [image: Zapier error]

Does someone have a solution for this?

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/J6TTteRkTYs

Comment: This is a great thing to write into support for: https://zapier.com/app/contact-us

Comment: Hi @xavdid, I've contacted the Zapier support,  I'll let know when I receive an answer.